# Monotonic function always has (±infinite) limit

Tags: limits, functions

Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ be an open interval, and $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a  monotonic function. Is it generally true that $ \lim_{x \rightarrow x'} f(x) $ exists or is $\pm \infty$ , if $x' \in \mathrm{cl} \ A$?

Is there a neat way to prove this? If one doesn't want to show the result for all different cases separately.

Comment: Take $f(x)=0$ for $x <0$ and $1$ for $x \geq 0$. Let $x'=0$. Does the limit exist?

Comment: The sign function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function is monotone, but has no limit at $x=0$.

Comment: What about if x' is a boundary point of the closure of A? Or $x'=\pm \infty$?

Comment: Monotonic functions always have *one-sided* limits. Whether the left-hand and right-hand limit coincides or not is another story.

Comment: @SangchulLee $A$ is specified to be an open interval

Comment: @GregMartin, Ah, I missed that. Thank you for pointing out my mistake! I now fixed my answer.

Comment: That's still not an open interval....

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks, so my question really should have been about existence of one-sided limit (if limit $\pm \infty$ is accepted as well) when the function is monotonic.

Comment: @GregMartin, I think my brain is only half awake, not properly working now. :( Thank you again. I will grab a cup of espresso to see if I can read the question correctly then.

Answer (score 0):

I will prove:

> **Claim.** Suppose $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a non-empty subset, and consider a non-decreasing function $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$. If $a$ is a "right accumulation point" of $A$, in the sense that $A \cap (x, a) \neq \varnothing$ for any $x < a$, then
> $$ \lim_{x \to a^-} f(x) = \sup \{ f(x) : x \in A \text{ and } x < a \}. $$

The proof is quite straightforward. Denote by $s$ the supremum in the right-hand side. Then

- $f(x) \leq s$ for all $x \in A$ with $x < a$, and so,
  $$ \limsup_{x \to a^-} f(x) \leq s. $$
- We can pick $x_n \in A$ such that $ x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < \cdots < a$ and $\lim f(x_n) = s$. Then
  $$ f(x_n) \leq \inf_{A \cap [x_n, a)} f(x) \leq \liminf_{x \to a^-} f(x), $$
  and so, letting $n \to \infty$ gives
  $$ s \leq \liminf_{x \to a^-} f(x). $$

These altogether show that $ \lim_{x \to a^-} f(x)$ exists and is equal to $s$.